# How to pull only the nodes/values from firebase and not the keys?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, firebase

How do you only pull only the nodes from firebase and not the keys using javascript? In other words, I only want the values of the key-value pairs from the below firebase, which means I don't want the unique keys below but just what's underneath.

[image: Firebase Data Structure]

Currently, my code is..

```
function PullFirebase() {
    new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/quakes').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var S = snapshot.val();

        function printData(data) {
            var f = eval(data);
            console.log(data + "(" + f.length + ") = " + JSON.stringify(f).replace("[", "[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g, "},\n\t").replace("]", "\n]"));
        }
        printData(S);
    });
}
PullFirebase();
```

This produces the following in the console

```
[object Object](undefined) = {"-JStYZoJ7PWK1gM4n1M6":{"FID":"quake.2013p618454","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"24.5703","latitude":"-41.5396","longitude":"174.1242","magnitude":"1.7345","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.12425 -41.539614)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:52:50.074","phases":"17","publicid":"2013p618454","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:54:11.27"},
    "-JStYZsd6j4Cm6GZtrrD":{"FID":"quake.2013p618440","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"26.3281","latitude":"-38.8725","longitude":"175.9561","magnitude":"2.6901","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (175.95611 -38.872468)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:45:25.076","phases":"13","publicid":"2013p618440","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:48:15.374"},...
```

but I'd like to only have the dictionaries , such as

```
[{"FID":"quake.2013p618454","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"24.5703","latitude":"-41.5396","longitude":"174.1242","magnitude":"1.7345","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.12425 -41.539614)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:52:50.074","phases":"17","publicid":"2013p618454","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:54:11.27"},{"FID":"quake.2013p597338","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"5.0586","latitude":"-37.8523","longitude":"176.8801","magnitude":"2.2362","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (176.88006 -37.852307)","origintime":"2013-08-10T00:21:54.989","phases":"17","publicid":"2013p597338","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-10T03:42:41.324"}...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get all child objects under `quakes`.

You generally have two approach here:

1. Get the value of the parent node and **loop** over the children
2. **Monitor** as children are added/updated/removed to the parent node

Your approach matches with #1, so I'll answer that one first. I'll also give an example of approach #2, which is more efficient when your data set changes.

### Iterate children of a Firebase ref

In your `on('value',` handler you can skip the unique IDs using [`forEach`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html):

```
new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/quakes').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var quakes = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        quakes.push(childSnapshot.val());
    });
    var filter = new crossfilter(quakes);

});
```

The `forEach` function is sychronous, so we can simply wait for the loop to finish and then create the crossfilter.

### Monitor children of a Firebase ref

In that case, the best construct is:

```
var quakes = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/quakes');
var quakeCount = 0;
quakes.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var quake = snapshot.val();
    quakeCount++;
    console.log("quakeCount="+quakeCount+", FID="+quake.FID);
});
quakes.on('child_removed', function (old_snapshot) {
    var quake = old_snapshot.val();
    quakeCount--;
    console.log("quakeCount="+quakeCount+", removed FID="+quake.FID);
});
```

With this code construct you're actively listening for quakes that are added and removed. You'll still have to keep an array of all the quakes, which you then modify in `child_added`, `child_changed` and `child_removed`.

### How they compare

When you first run the code, monitoring for children will result in the same data as the `on('value',` construct. But when children are added/removed later `on('value',` will receive all quakes again, while `on('child_added',` and `on('child_removed',` will only be called for the quake in question.