# How to pull data from firebase to put into crossfilter?

Tags: firebase, crossfilter

I'd like to pull data from the Firebase database in order to pass into crossfilter. However, I'm having difficulty understanding the structure output data from Firebase needs to be in in order to be an argument for crossfilter.

The following is the structure of the data that is outputted from Firebase:

```
[object Object](undefined) = {"-JStYZoJ7PWK1gM4n1M6":{"FID":"quake.2013p618454","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"24.5703","latitude":"-41.5396","longitude":"174.1242","magnitude":"1.7345","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.12425 -41.539614)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:52:50.074","phases":"17","publicid":"2013p618454","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:54:11.27"},
    "-JStYZsd6j4Cm6GZtrrD":{"FID":"quake.2013p618440","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"26.3281","latitude":"-38.8725","longitude":"175.9561","magnitude":"2.6901","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (175.95611 -38.872468)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:45:25.076","phases":"13","publicid":"2013p618440","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:48:15.374"},
    "-JStYZw6bhnFhYYwe0JI":{"FID":"quake.2013p618439","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"27.0312","latitude":"-41.8992","longitude":"174.3117","magnitude":"4.6968","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.31173 -41.899212)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:44:28.998","phases":"130","publicid":"2013p618439","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:48:39.064"},
    "-JStY_-q5x78w9VkRfpw":{"FID":"quake.2013p618432","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"5.9961","latitude":"-41.7495","longitude":"174.02","magnitude":"1.8642","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.02 -41.749481)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:40:45.348","phases":"11","publicid":"2013p618432","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:42:33.279"},
    "-JStY_4cCuMKZkGfgH9P":{"FID":"quake.2013p618429","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","depth":"5.9375","latitude":"-41.7008","longitude":"174.0876","magnitude":"2.1629","magnitudetype":"M","origin_geom":"POINT (174.08765 -41.700788)","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:39:16.665","phases":"19","publicid":"2013p618429","status":"automatic","type":"","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:41:32.969"}...
```

which I generated with the following code

```
function PullFirebase() {
    new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/quakes').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var Data = snapshot.val();

        function printData(data) {
            var f = eval(data);
            console.log(data + "(" + f.length + ") = " + JSON.stringify(f).replace("[", "[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g, "},\n\t").replace("]", "\n]"));
        }
        printData(Data);
    });
}
PullFirebase();
```

I receive this error when I try to put the 'Data' above from firebase into crossfilter

```
[object Object](undefined) = {}
```

It seems that I need to turn Firebase output into an object literal, because I know the following structure works when it's taken in as an argument for firebase:

```
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object](5) = [{"FID":"quake.2013p618454","publicid":"2013p618454","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:52:50.074","longitude":"174.1242","latitude":"-41.5396","depth":25,"magnitude":"1.7345","magnitudetype":"M","status":"automatic","phases":"17","type":"","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:54:11.27","origin_geom":"POINT (174.12425 -41.539614)","dtg":"2013-08-17T23:52:50.000Z","lat":-41.5396,"long":174.1242,"mag":1.7},
    {"FID":"quake.2013p618440","publicid":"2013p618440","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:45:25.076","longitude":"175.9561","latitude":"-38.8725","depth":26,"magnitude":"2.6901","magnitudetype":"M","status":"automatic","phases":"13","type":"","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:48:15.374","origin_geom":"POINT (175.95611 -38.872468)","dtg":"2013-08-17T23:45:25.000Z","lat":-38.8725,"long":175.9561,"mag":2.7},
    {"FID":"quake.2013p618439","publicid":"2013p618439","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:44:28.998","longitude":"174.3117","latitude":"-41.8992","depth":27,"magnitude":"4.6968","magnitudetype":"M","status":"automatic","phases":"130","type":"","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:48:39.064","origin_geom":"POINT (174.31173 -41.899212)","dtg":"2013-08-17T23:44:28.000Z","lat":-41.8992,"long":174.3117,"mag":4.7},
    {"FID":"quake.2013p618432","publicid":"2013p618432","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:40:45.348","longitude":"174.02","latitude":"-41.7495","depth":6,"magnitude":"1.8642","magnitudetype":"M","status":"automatic","phases":"11","type":"","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:42:33.279","origin_geom":"POINT (174.02 -41.749481)","dtg":"2013-08-17T23:40:45.000Z","lat":-41.7495,"long":174.02,"mag":1.9},
    {"FID":"quake.2013p618429","publicid":"2013p618429","origintime":"2013-08-17T19:39:16.665","longitude":"174.0876","latitude":"-41.7008","depth":6,"magnitude":"2.1629","magnitudetype":"M","status":"automatic","phases":"19","type":"","agency":"WEL(GNS_Primary)","updatetime":"2013-08-17T19:41:32.969","origin_geom":"POINT (174.08765 -41.700788)","dtg":"2013-08-17T23:39:16.000Z","lat":-41.7008,"long":174.0876,"mag":2.2}]
```

Comment: This fiddle shows your data structure and how to cleanly get it from JavaScript into Firebase and from Firebase into HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/SkW6T/. I'll have a look at Crossfilter next, but you should be able to simply pass those Firebase objects into it (possibly after `push`ing them into a local array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example, using the `on('value',` approach that you have in your question:

```
new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/quakes').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var quakes = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        quakes.push(childSnapshot.val());
    });
    var filter = new crossfilter(quakes);
    console.log(xf.groupAll().reduceCount().value());
    var quakesByMagnitude = xf.dimension(function(q) { return q.magnitude; });
    quakesByMagnitude.filterRange([1,2]); // filters the original list
    console.log(xf.groupAll().reduceCount().value());
});
```

This fiddle shows this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/SkW6T/

Note that I provided a similar answer to your other question: [How to pull only the nodes/values from firebase and not the keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992867/how-to-pull-only-the-nodes-values-from-firebase-and-not-the-keys). There I also explain an alternative approach, where you monitor the `quakes` list for changes instead of iterating over all children on every change.